# how to change tab highlight color, change tab divider color, reduce action bar stacked margin

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I am working on custom tab in view pager.

I want to display tabview of view pager like this.

[image]

1)Extra textview on right hand side of every tab
 So i inflate layout and add as custom layout for tab in view pager but it look like as picture below.(its some related to margin and padding but i dont know how can i fix that)

2) I want to change tab divider color 
3) I want to change tab selected highlight from blue to orange.
I search on google but i dont found anything.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you to generate the styles automatically as you design. 
[Go to this link](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) and generate your design and download the zip and replace the syles with project styles. This might help you.